# How to change legend title of scale_fill_gradient2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the title of a legend I'm using in ggplot. The functions I'm using to make the scale of colour is `scale_fill_gradient2` this is my code for the map

```
#Importing a map
world = ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
city = data.frame(long = -63.58, lat = 44.65, label = "Halifax")
city1 = data.frame(long = -63.58, lat = 44.85, label = "Halifax")


#map of total detections in each zone per month
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_rect(data = individual_dets, mapping = aes(xmin = -62.8, xmax = -64.5, ymin = 42.7, ymax = 45, fill = ave_temp)) +

#How to change the name of this legend?
  scale_fill_gradient2( 
                        low = "yellow", mid = "springgreen", high = "lightblue") + 
  geom_sf() +
  #coordinates of my map
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45), expand = FALSE) +
  #Showing the 4 zones as boxes... need to fix
  geom_rect(data = rect1, aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2), fill = NA, color = "black", size = 1) +
  #plotting the distribution across shelf by unique detections
  new_scale('fill') +
  geom_point(data = individual_dets,
             mapping = aes(x = longitude, 
                           y = latitude,
                           color = num_unique_tags,
                           fill = num_unique_tags),
             pch = 21, size = 5, alpha = 0.5) +
  #fill the unique detections with viridis
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "D", guide = F) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "D", guide = F) +

  #trying to get color of ocean on a scale  
#####


###


  #formatting
#Could maybe use for ocean temp ave scale?
######
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFF00"),
#####

        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),

        strip.background =  element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA), 
        strip.text =        element_text(size = 25),

        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 25,
                    family = "sans"),
        legend.title = element_text("Average Temp"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +

  facet_wrap(vars(month)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = long, y = lat, label = label),
              data = city1,
              position = position_dodge(width=0.2),  size=6) +

  geom_point(data = city, color = "red",
             mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 5)
```

I've tried using

```
labs = "Average Temp"
```

and I've also tried

```
legend.title = element_text("Average Temp")
```

But neither of them change the name of my legend. Does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: you can try scale_fill_gradient2(name="Average Temp")

Comment: can you add the packages you use to your script? I don't know where `ne_countries` comes from. Or make a minimal example that doesn't depend on external data.